# Html.fromHtml() in Android won't allow you to click on links

Tags: android, html

My links show up blue in my text view. So it's definitely being read as a link. Works in my iOS app. But clicking on it in Android doesn't work.

My setup:

```
textView.setText(toHtml(htmlString));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setLinksClickable(true);
textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Here is my `toHtml(String html)` method

```
public static Spanned toHtml(String string) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        return Html.fromHtml(string, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY); // for 24 api and more
    } else {
        return Html.fromHtml(string); // or for older api
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the cause of this could be?

I know this question has been asked multiple times on SO, but most of the answers are to `setMovementMethod()`, `setLinksClickable()`, or `setAutoLinkMask()` which still doesn't work. I've setting those methods in different combinations with still no luck. My xml is plain. It just has an id, width and height. Nothing involving links/urls.